# Double Pulse Test setup layout consideration

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, layout

[image]

[image]

I am new into PCB Design and wanted some suggestions for the layout for double pulse test.

1. Regarding placements of the components (inductors, capacitors, gate driver, MOSFETs)
2. How many layers? 2? How should I decide which component to be in which layer?
3. Where all to consider clearances? (Operating voltage 100 V DC, operating current ~ 30 A)

Comment: You should first evaluate the "powers" in that circuit, Currents and voltages in all components. Do you need heatsink (s)? The "power parts" of the circuit should have the lowest "inductance" ... 30 A and 100 V make 3 kW ... What are Q1 and Q2 ?

Comment: See this also https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/128885920/01_PID3339401.pdf

Comment: @Antonio51 Q1 and Q2 are mosfets .. heatsink not required because testup will be run for some micro-seconds.